# How to get the value of a variable from subprocess and use it in another program

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

**Question**

I am running a python code - main.py - in which I am calling a subprocess - subprocess.py, with command line arguments. I want to be able to access the variable returned at the end of subprocess.py in main.py.

**My codes**:

**sub.py**

```
import optparse
#ANSI escape sequence
BOLD = "\033[1m"
RED = "\033[1;31m"
END = "\033[0m"

def parser():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option(
        "-n", help="Enter a number: ", dest='n')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    n = options.n
    return n

def main():
    n = parser()
    print(BOLD + RED + f'Your number is {n}' + END)
    z = int(n)**2
    return z

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = main()
```

**main.py**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('python /home/username/sub.py -n 2', shell=True) #This one just runs sub.py on the terminal with the ANSI escape sequence but does not return the variable z.

output = subprocess.check_output('python /home/username/sub.py -n 2', shell=True) 
print(output) #This one runs sub.py but just dumps the output in the terminal without the ANSI escape sequence and does not return the variable z.
```

I want to be able to run sub.py with the ANSI escape sequence in the terminal from main.py and then be able to use the variable z in main.py. Also, is there a better way to do these two things other than subprocess? Any help/inputs would be appreciated. Thank you.

**My solution:**
I solved it by first making a function (for_sub(n)) in main.py which takes n as input rather than from the parser. I then called the parser function (parser()) in main.py and passed the value to n to for_sub(n).

**sub.py**

```
import optparse
#ANSI escape sequence
BOLD = "\033[1m"
RED = "\033[1;31m"
END = "\033[0m"

def parser():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option(
        "-n", help="Enter a number: ", dest='n')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    n = options.n
    return n

def for_main(n):
    print(BOLD + RED + f'Your number is {n}' + END)
    z = int(n)**2
    return z

def main():
    n = parser()
    print(BOLD + RED + f'Your number is {n}' + END)
    z = int(n)**2
    return z

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main.py**

```
import sub import parser
from sub import for_main
import optparse

#ANSI escape sequence
BOLD = "\033[1m"
RED = "\033[1;31m"
END = "\033[0m"

def main():
   n = parser()
   z = for_main(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot import subprocess.py and call it's main from within your program?

Comment: Subprocesses don't return values how you are envisioning they do. The only output they can provide is limited to stdout/stderr and the returncode (unless you involve more complex [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) strategies). This case doesn't seem well suited to subprocessing in the first place. I recommend creating python modules instead as @saquintes suggests.

Comment: better `import subprocess` and run `sys.argv.extend( ['-n', '2'] ) ; z = subprocess.main()`. You could even edit `subprocess.py` to run as `main(parser())` so later you can run it as `subprocess.main(2)`

Comment: @saquintes No specific reason for not using modules. I just wanted to explore the possibilities. In the end, I got it done with modules. Thank you very much

Comment: @NealTitusThomas: Understood.  If for some reason you needed them to be in separate processes, then you'd want to look at potentially using the multiprocessing library and there's also a shared memory library in the standard library.  Or you can use pickle to pass python objects/values between processes. Or if it's just an integer you could possibly make it part of the output.  But if in a different process, python programs have no way of accessing other script's variables outside of the SharedMemory stuff I mentioned.